# Summon all php classes on load web page

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to create a class that loads all the classes when any site in the web loads. Here you have the classes that I want to load:

```
<?php

include_once filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/Config.inc.php";

class Connection extends Conf{

    private static $connection;
    private static $config;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->config = new Conf;
    }
```

Note: That class extends Conf (config.inc.php file) because the method that gets the data is protected, not public.

And also I want to load the following class:

```
<?php

/*
 * 
 * El contenido de este archivo está protegido y para incluirse debe extenderse a la clase Config
 * 
 */

 Class Conf {

    private static $db_server = "server";
    private static $db_user = "username";
    private static $db_pass = "password";
    private static $db_maindb = "database";

    private static $server_folder = "folder";

     public function __construct(){

         $this->db_server = "server";
         $this->db_user = "username";
         $this->db_pass = "password";
         $this->db_maindb = "database";

         $this->server_folder = "folder";

     }
```

I'm sure that it's something like this:

```
class Builder {
 public function build(){
  Connection::__construct();
  Conf::__construct();
 }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Some help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing static variables and class variables here.

You are trying to set static variables on the class using $this, which relates to the instance of the class. To set the static variables you should use self::,Inside the __construct - which gets called when you create an instance of the class i.e:

```
<?php
$blah = new Conf();
```

Also, your first classe is strange, as you're extending Conf, but also creating a new instance of it in the constructor.

I think it would make more sense to have all of your variables defined in the config file as constants, and then you could create a new config class passing those constants in as parameters to the constructor, making it able to be reused later.

Config.inc.php

```
<?php
define("SERVER", "hostname");
define("USERNAME", "username");
define("PASSWORD", "P@ssw0rd");
define("DATABASE", "maindb");
```

And your classes like this:

```
<?php


include_once filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/Config.inc.php";


class Connection
{

    private $connection;
    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->config->getServer(), $this->config->getUsername(), $this->config->getPassword(), $this->config->getDatabase());
    }
}


    class Config
    {

        private $server;
        private $username;
        private $password;
        private $database;

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getServer()
        {
            return $this->server;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $server
         */
        public function setServer($server)
        {
            $this->server = $server;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $username
         */
        public function setUsername($username)
        {
            $this->username = $username;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $password
         */
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getDatabase()
        {
            return $this->database;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $database
         */
        public function setDatabase($database)
        {
            $this->database = $database;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getServerFolder()
        {
            return $this->server_folder;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $server_folder
         */
        public function setServerFolder($server_folder)
        {
            $this->server_folder = $server_folder;
        }

        private $server_folder;

        public function __construct($server, $username, $password, $database)
        {

            $this->server = $server;
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->database = $database;

            $this->server_folder = "folder";

        }
    }
```

And then, finally to use it:

```
<?php

    $config = new Config($server, $username, $password, $database);

    $connection = new Connection($config);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the tutorial. I thought I needed to use a similar way to Java, I mean, call them using functions and not referring to them as static xD

Comment: Also, I thought that if you define them as global constants you can access while the web page is loading. I'll keep my way because needs of an extension to access them. I mean, a protected function is a function that needs a extends to be summoned. Then access it from any page that's not the original or the one that extends the original makes it impossible to summon. I'm trying to keep my site most secure as possible :P

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by when the web page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Error on your code,

first of all static properties cannot be accessed via -> operators

```
         $this->db_server = "server";
         $this->db_user = "username";
         $this->db_pass = "password";
         $this->db_maindb = "database";

         $this->server_folder = "folder";
```

Try using self:: for static members to work

```
     self::$db_server = "server";
     self::$db_user = "username";
     self::$db_pass = "password";
     self::$db_maindb = "database";

     self::$server_folder = "folder";
```

You might want to look on [spl auto loader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) so that whenever the class is declared, it would load file automatically and you wont have to include classes by yourself

```
    <? // scInit.php
    define("SC_ROOT", dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );
    define("SC_PREFIX", "sc");
    define("SC_EXTENSION", ".php");
    spl_autoload_register(
            function ($namespace) {
                $parts=explode('\\', $namespace);
                $class_name= end($parts); /// break namespaces and take last part as class name.

                $fileDirectory = array("model", "view", "controller", "admin", "registry"); // Directories to look for the class file
                foreach ($fileDirectory as $directory) {
                    $classFileName = SC_ROOT .$directory."/". SC_PREFIX . $class_name . SC_EXTENSION;
                    if (file_exists($classFileName)) {
                        include_once($classFileName);
                    }
                }
        });
```

and

```
 <?php 
//index.php

namespace project\admin;
include_once("scInit.php");

use project\model\TimeStamp;

$con=  new TimeStamp(); 

/* class TimeStamp is not loaded so now it will run spl_autoloader before generating fatal error passing project\model\TimeStamp as parameter. 
spl_autoloader will look for scTimeStamp.php in all directories defined in autoload function.

*/
```

And I am assuming you are trying to load connection credentials for mysql. Please visit once [DBCon](https://github.com/narayangt/PHP-DBCon-INI) which might be useful to you